# How to convert string to Objectify command?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm developing GAE project using Datastore and Objectify. When developing queries I need some query that is dependent on runtime values. For example it depends on conditions including dynamically changed costumer demands on **unknown ammount of parameters**

```
ofy().load().type(Car.class)
.filter("year =", 1999)
.filter("price = ", 30000)
.filter("color = ","grey")
.filter("
.........
.filter("width",2.1)
.filter and so on )
.list();
```

When solving this problem **in SQL I used strings constructed in loops** to construct and then execute such statements including conditions. How to solve it in Objectify? Thank in advance

Comment: The first thing to point consider is that you will need a composite index for each combination of filters.

Comment: Composite index or composite filters are not that I need. I need something like: String str=".filter(\"year =\", 1999).filter(\"price = \", 30000).filter(\"color = \",\"grey\")" that could be joined with ofy().load().type(Car.class) + str in some manner and executed... Thanks @tx802

Comment: But you *will* still need a composite index for each combination of filters. Even if you find a way to dynamically construct a chain of Objectify filters, your query will not work without a composite index.